# Message window for Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, messagebox

I am using MAC OS, for a python program. I want to display a messagebox if the condition is true. Could someone tell me how to create a Python messagebox for macOS which can be called when the condition is `True` or `False`?

I tried

```
import subprocess

applescript = """
display dialog "Some message goes here..." ¬
with title "This is a pop-up window" ¬
with icon caution ¬buttons {"OK"}"""

subprocess.call("osascript -e '{}'".format(applescript), shell=True)
```

But this, I don't know how to call depending on the condition.

Comment: Depending on which condition?

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

# An error box
if(condition)
    tkMessageBox.showerror("Error","No disk space left on device")

# A warning box 
if(condition)
    tkMessageBox.showwarning("Warning","Could not start 
service")

# An information box
if(condition)
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Information","Created in Python.")
```

Comment: Hi, this tkinter message box appears only when I close another frame which is currently doing some functions. In my program

Comment: Hi, this Tkinter message box appears only when I close another frame which is currently performing some functions. In my program, I have a Tkinter form called 'Register User', I am checking the whether the details of the user is duplicate or not, if duplicate, the program has to display an error message on clicking the submit button.                                           But as of now what is happening is that the error message box appears only when the registration is closed. I want this to be top of the already opened RegistrationForm. Could someone help how to do this?